# Export SQL result set in UTF-8 in Shell script

Tags: sql, oracle, shell, unix, sh

I am extracting data set into a file through shell script. But Arabic characters coming with ??? character. How to load these character to UTf-8 format to get proper Character set result in a file.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First ensure that your terminal is set to UTF-8 by `locale charmap` or `echo $LANG`

The set your `NLS_LANG` environment variable, for example `export NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8`

Comment: I need it only for particular session where  I am running the shell script.  Is it the same thing I have to du?

Comment: You can run in sqlplus a host command `host export NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8` but I don't know if this affects the current session.